# My hamburger menu isnt working I dont know why

Tags: javascript, html

guys, I am trying to get my hamburger button to work but nothing is happening does anyone have any advice?

here  is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>


    <title>David Underwood</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="/" class="header-logo">
        <h3>Welcome</h3>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <img class="union" src="Union.png" alt="menu link" />
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="greet">
      <div class="top-row-one">
        <h2 class="porto">Portoflio</h2>
        <h3 class="about-top">About</h3>
        <h4 class="con">Contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1 class="hi-there">Hey there. I’m <br />David</h1>
        <h2 class="hi-there2">
          I’m a software <br />
          developer
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="greeting2">
        <h1 class="header-title">Hey there. I’m David.</h1>
        <h1>
          <span>I’m a software developer</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <p class="paragraph1">
        I can help you build a product, <br />
        feature or website Look through <br />
        some of my work and experience! <br />
        If you like what you see and have <br />
        a project you need coded, <br />
        don’t hestiate to contact me.
      </p>

      <div class="para-box">
        <p class="paragraph2">
          I can help you build a product , feature or website Look through some
          of my work and <br />
          experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need
          coded, <br />
          don’t hestiate to contact me.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <ul class="icon-row">
          <li>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/david630"
              ><img class="tweet" src="twitter.svg" alt="twitter picture"
            /></a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <img class="med" src="medium.svg" alt="medium picture" />
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/david63011"
              ><img class="git" src="github.svg" alt="git picture"
            /></a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <img class="angel" src="angellist.svg" alt="angelist picture" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-info">
        <h1 class="works">
          My Recent <br />
          Works
        </h1>
        <img class="Indicator" src="Indicator.png" alt="green line" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <h2 class="works2">My Recent Works</h2>

    <section class="grid-containers"> 
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="column1"></div>
        <div class="column2">
          <div class="project-box">
            <h1 class="project-name1">Multi-Post Stories</h1>
            <h1 class="project-name-two">Gain+Glory</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="languages">
            <ul>
              <li class="ruby">Ruby on Rails</li>
              <li class="css">css</li>
              <li class="js">JavScript</li>
              <li class="html">HTML</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="see-project-btn">See Project</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="picture-box">
      <section class="about">
        <div class="about-me">About Me</div>
      </section>
      <section class="text-box1">
        <div class="text-info1">
          <p class="p2">
            I can help you build a product, <br />
            feature or website Look through <br />
            some of my work and experience! If <br />
            you like what you see and have a <br />
            project you need coded, <br />
            don’t hestiate to contact me.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="text-box2">
        <div class="text-info2">
          <h2 class="text1a">
            I can help you build a product , feature or website Look through
            some of my work and
          </h2>
          <h3 class="text-info2b">
            experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need
            coded,
          </h3>
          <h4 class="text-info3c">don’t hestiate to contact me.</h4>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="resume-btn">Get My Resume</button>

    <section class="new-end-section">
      <ul class="about-me-end-section">
        <li>
          <div class="type-of-cards">
            <div class="cat-images">
              <img src="ball.svg" alt="picture of globe" />
            </div>

            <h2 class="cat-title">Languages</h2>

            <ul class="cat-things">
              <li>JavaScript</li>
              <li>Ruby</li>
              <li>Html</li>
              <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="type-of-cards">
            <div class="cat-images">
              <img src="frame.svg" alt="picture of globe" />
            </div>

            <h2 class="cat-title">Frameworks</h2>
            <div>
              <ul class="cat-things">
                <li>Bootstrap</li>
                <li>Ruby on rails</li>
                <li>RSpec</li>
                <li>Capybara</li>
                <li>Selenium</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="type-of-cards">
            <div class="cat-images">
              <img src="ball.svg" alt="picture of globe" />
            </div>

            <h2 class="cat-title">Skills</h2>

            <ul class="cat-things">
              <li>Codekit</li>
              <li>Github</li>
              <li>CodePen</li>
              <li>GitLab</li>
              <li>Terminal</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <footer class="contactpage">
      <section class="projects-end">
        <h2 class="textline1">I'm always</h2>
        <h3 class="textline2">interested in</h3>
        <h4 class="textline3">hearing about</h4>
        <h5 class="textline4">new projects, so</h5>
        <h6 class="textline5">if you'd like to</h6>
        <h6 class="textline6">chat please get</h6>
        <h6 class="textline7">in touch</h6>
      </section>
      <section class="projects-2-big">
        <div class="new-paragraph">
          I'm always interested in hearing about new projects, so if you'd like
          to chat please get in touch.
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="form-section">
        <div class="form-container">
          <form action="https://formspree.io/f/myyvzkag" method="post">
            <ul class="form-info">
              <li>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  maxlength="30"
                  name="user_name"
                  class="name-text-box"
                  id="full-name"
                  placeholder="Full Name"
                  required=""
                />
              </li>

              <li>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="user_email"
                  class="name-last-text-box"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  required=""
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <textarea
                  id="text-box"
                  name="message"
                  maxlength="500"
                  class="enter-form"
                  cols="30"
                  rows="10"
                  placeholder="Enter text here"
                  required=""
                ></textarea>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </form>
          <input type="submit" value="Get in touch" class="send-btn" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="touch-btn2">Get in touch</button>
        <img class="rec" src="rec.png" alt="long line" />
      </section>
      <div class="icon-row-footer">
        <div class="tweet-connect">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/david630"
            ><img class="tweet" src="twitter.svg" alt="twitter picture"
          /></a>
        </div>

        <img class="med" src="medium.svg" alt="medium picture" />
        <div>
          <a href="https://github.com/david63011"
            ><img class="git" src="github.svg" alt="git picture"
          /></a>
        </div>

        <img class="angel" src="angellist.svg" alt="angelist picture" />
      </div>

      <p class="email">david630@gmail.com</p>

      <div class="black">
        <img class="Indicator2" src="Indicator.png" alt="green line" />
      </div>
    </footer>
  
    <!--Footer section end-->
    <!--overlay section start-->
     <div class="over">
       <div class="cancel">
        <a href="#"><img src=cancel.png alt="close-icon-button"></a>
       </div>
       <ul class="main-overlay-menu">
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item" href="#grid-containers">Portofolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="menu-item" href="#contactpage">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>


  
  
  

  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector('.union');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.over');
const menu = document.querySelector('.main-overlay-menu');

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  overlay.style.display = 'flex';
  menu.style.display = 'block';
});
```

When I click the hamburger icon nothing happens. And I don't know why so any help would be appreciated. I think the javascript is ok but maybe its now so any help on that area would also be apprecaited

Comment: This is too much code and it doesn't run... Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok I will make a new question

Answer (score -1):

you can try to using getElemantById or className.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).